# DOMException: Could not start video source with zxing and bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webrtc, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using [@zxing/ngx-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner), **Angular 7** and [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) modal.

In my application, I put **ngx-scanner** into a modal, when user click on a specific button, browser will ask for user camera access permission and display the modal dialog which contains `zxing/ngx-scanner`.

I access my web application using **Android XPERIA XA1** and **Chrome 70.0.3538.80**.

With front camera, it is always fine. But when I change to rear camera, an error is thrown back to me: **DOMException: Could not start video source**.

It is very frustrating, I have been searching for this issue hours and hours but found nothing.

Here is my reproduce on [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-cztk8r).

*I already checked the camera access permission conflict between apps and browsers, but nothing occupies the camera access.*

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: it is a bit hard to determine without the unminified source, linking that would improve the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I updated the link above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically that error happens when you do not close the front camera using stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop() before calling getUserMedia again to acquire the rear camera. Android devices are typically limited to one open camera at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I have realized `getUserMedia` already opens a stream. 
When I iterate through every track of that stream and stop them, my app worked fine.

Comment: Useful when you take the camera stream and connect it to a video element like  `video.srcObject`
before switching the camera source, stop all tracks with `video?.srcObject?.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());`

Then continue with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)...`

Comment: @Redplane Please tell the code, what did you add?